# Maximum call stack size exceeded issue with base ref

Tags: angularjs, html

Please check my Angular template. Application freeze and error in the console is **"Maximum call stack size exceeded"**. When I remove base ref tag page is ok. How to use base url without this issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="/">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div class="wrapper">
<div style="background-color:#333;border:1px solid black">
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Home </a></li>
  <li><a href="customer">Customer</a></li>
  <li><a href="Quotation">Quotation</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>
<script src="js/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/route.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

error

[image]

rout js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'index.html',controller  : 'myCtrl'
  }).when('/customer', {
        templateUrl : 'customer.html',
  })    
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Comment: Your app.js route.js?

Comment: Dear hamzox.. check rout js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs due to recursively inserting `index.html` to `ng-view`.

remove `when('/', {templateUrl : 'index.html',controller  : 'myCtrl'})` part from your code as follows and check again.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/customer', {
    templateUrl : 'customer.html',
  })    
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```